# Exercise with loops and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

While practicing programming on coding challenges I ran into this problem and I'm stuck on it. You have two arrays:

```
int[] fromArray
int[] toArray
```

They hold values of 'nodes' (from and to node). Index are related like this fromArray[1] -> toArray[1], fromArray[2] -> toArray[2], .... It is something like linked lists. So for example in fromArray on index 0, you have value 1, and then on index 0 in toArray you have 4. Then you have for example on index 2 in fromArray value 4, and on index 2 in toArray value 9. This means that value 1 is connected to 4, and 4 is connected to 9.

I need to find last node (node that doesn't have connected node). If there is no such, then it's circular, and I need to print last node before it becomes circular.

This is standard example, result should be 8:

```
int[] fromArray = new int[] {1, 4, 6, 2};
int[] toArray = new int[] {4, 6, 8, 5};
```

As special case we have circular list, e.g.

```
int[] fromArray = new int[] {1, 4, 6, 2};
int[] toArray = new int[] {4, 6, 1, 5};
```

The result should be 6 (that is the last node before connecting 1 to 1 (making this list circular)..

This was my closest try, but still I think that I'm nowhere the right path to solve this. I thought that I can solve this by finding which element is in toArray but isn't in fromArray, but that is not the right solution:

```
public static int findLastNode(int[] fromArray, int[] toArray){
    int lastNode = -1;
    boolean found = false;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < fromArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < fromArray.length; j++){
            if (toArray[i] == fromArray[j]){
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if (found){
            found = false;
        }
        else {
            lastNode = toArray[i];
            return lastNode;
        }
       
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < toArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < toArray.length; j++){
            if (toArray[i] == toArray[j]){
                lastNode = toArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return lastNode;
}
```

Comment: Does the pattern of mapping changes? because it's a bit unclear what is the pattern.. in the first case you have `1 -> 4`, and `4 -> 9`. Seems like increment with 3 and with 5 (so, next can be with 7).. but in another example, you say, result should be `8`.. and there I'm lost. Are you sure you have a correct formulation of your task?

Comment: The case that you call the special circular case really contains both a circular and a non-circular graph. 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 1 is circular. 2 -> 5 is non-circular. So would be 5 be a correct answer? When there are more than one graph, is there a rule for which one to report?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri there is no specific pattern for this in incrementing

Comment: @OleV.V.  It must start with the first element of array.

Comment: If the graph is 2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 3, should 7 be returned? The arrays could be for instance `{ 2, 3, 7 }` and `{ 3, 7, 3 }`. In this case the cycle does not go back to where we began.

Answer (score 1):

You are overthinking it. Try to take it step by step and write them on a piece of paper.

You know for sure that `fromArray[0]` is "linked" to `toArray[0]`. In that case you can assume that `lastNode` will be `toArray[0]` even before you will run your algorithm. After that, you need to check if there are any "linked values" in `fromArray`. If yes, change `lastNode` to `toArray` at the index of that link.

Now, you need to think about the case, when the links are circular.

The circularity is when `lastNode` is same as our `fromArray[0]`, since it is starting point of our links. So if, the `lastNode` is equal to `fromArray[0]`, you need to return value from `fromArray` at the same index that `lastNode` was found. To avoid second loop (to find that index), you can save it into the variable `lastNodeIndex`.

Finally, we end up with this algorithm:

```
public static int findLastNode(int[] fromArray, int[] toArray) {
        int lastNode = toArray[0];
        int lastNodeIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < fromArray.length; i++) {
            if (fromArray[i] == lastNode) {
                lastNode = toArray[i];
                lastNodeIndex = i;
            }
        }
        return lastNode == fromArray[0] ? fromArray[lastNodeIndex] : lastNode;
    }
```

Comment: Are you assuming that the edges come in order in the arrays? If the arrays are `{ 1, 6, 4, 2 }` and `{ 4, 8, 6, 5 }`, I believe the graph is 1 -> 4 -> 6 -> 8, so the answer should be 8, but your code returns 6.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I assumed the edges are in order. In this case, the algorithm that I wrote should be modified so it will check the `fromArray` until there is no mapping with `toArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to walk through your graph from one node to the next until either there is no next node or the next node is your starting node, `fromArray[0]`. So code a loop to take such steps. You will want to have a variable for the current index into both arrays, the index of the current edge, so to speak. Whenever `toArray[currentIndex] == fromArray[0]`, you have detected a cycle. In this case return the node before the first node, that is, `fromArray[currentIndex]`. You can put the `return` statement inside your `if` statement inside your loop.

Each time through your loop try to find the next edge, that is, the index `i` where `fromArray[i] == toArray[currentIndex]`. You may use an inner loop or a stream pipeline. If there is no such index, you have found the last node. Return it.